# Incorrect data passed on first click of button

Tags: ios, swift

Salutations,

My problem is as follows, I have an app I am working on which contains two views. The first simply has 2 buttons labeled "Slide Show One", and "Slide Show Two".

When I click on the first button, it displays the information for the second slideshow as (due to my supreme novice-ness), I select which of the slideshows to select via a boolean as follows:

```
var button : Bool = false;
```

then:

```
@IBAction func slideShowOne() {
        button = true;
    }

@IBAction func slideShowTwo() {
        print("clicked button 2");
        button = false;
    }
```

Finally in the prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let passedPic = segue.destination as! ViewControllerTwo;
        if(button == true) {
            print(button);
            passedPic.picsChosen = sLS1;
        }
        if(button == false) {
            print(button);
            passedPic.picsChosen = sLS2;
        }
    }
```

Only way to have it display the correct information is by clicking on say button 1 for btn1 slideshow, going back, then clicking on button 1 again. Why is this, does it have anything to do with how swift handles function calls?

Aside: Swift knowledge is now a grand total of one week.

EDIT: Got it working, much appreciated. Now a quick question, at this time my two IBActions are empty, but required since they have segues attached to them, would be the best way to either make them meaningful, or perhaps still be able to segue; I assume the prepare function is an absolute must, otherwise there is no way (of which I know), to send the required data to my second VC.

```
@IBAction func slideShowOne() {
        //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "slideOne", sender: self);
    }

    @IBAction func slideShowTwo() {

        //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "slideTwo", sender: self);

    }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        let passedPic = segue.destination as! ViewControllerTwo;

        if(segue.identifier == "slideOne") {
            passedPic.picsChosen = sLS1;
        } else {
            passedPic.picsChosen = sLS2;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How do you call prepareForSegue ? Storyboard or you manually call it ?

Comment: I have it in my main viewController, the buttons are associated to an imageView in the second view via ctrl-dragging them using the storyboard. @Miknash is that what you meant by storyboard or manually?

Comment: Yeah, that is something that is executed via storyboard.

Comment: Still a bit new to all this, but my understanding was that we simply attach components to the storyboard, then create the corresponding funcs, outlets, etc. in the controllers to create the logic. How can I fix that strange behavior then?

Comment: posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try connecting view controller to view controller via storyboard - same ctrl dragging but whole view controller to other.

Give that segue identifier -> select identifier and on forth tab give it identfiier.

After that in one of your buttons, eg:

```
@IBAction func slideShowOne() {
    button = true;
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTheOtherVC", sender: self)
}
```

And you will have desired behaviour.

Comment: How to go about dragging the view controllers, does not seem to give that option.

Comment: Okay, i believe i found where the identifier was. Now it first quickly goes to the incorrect slideshow, then to the correct one. I suppose that we still do require a prepareForSegue function otherwise it won't send any data (at least it doesn't when I try it), correct?

Comment: Update: Almost there, it does send the correct value, however it appears to segue twice. I now use your suggestion, along with segue.identifier in my prepareForSegue function.

Comment: Remove the other segue-keep only one

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that: `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` always be executed firstly. 
So the actual workflow is as following:

-> 1) Initialize first view

-> 2) **var button = false**

-> 3) the user taps btn1

-> 4) `func prepare` is called

-> 5) second view is displayed **(`var button` is still false at this moment, that's why you get incorrect response)**

-> 6) `func slideShowOne()` is called (the user already is in second view)

->  7) **var button = true** caused by `func slideShowOne()` (the user already is in second view)

-> 8) the user goes back

-> 9) the user taps btn1 again

-> 10) `func prepare` is called

-> 11) second view is displayed **(the user gets correct response because value of `var button` has been changed in step7)**

Let me know if you have any other questions. Have fun. : )

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you for the clear explanation.